# Android ui testing fragment with Hilt

Tags: android, android-espresso, dagger-hilt

I want to write ui test  for my fragment. Now I am using hilt for dependency injection and navigation components .My ui test code is like this.

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class WelcomeFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    private val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

    @Before
    fun setUp(){
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun `testFragmentinits`(){
        launchWelcomeFragment()

    }

    private fun launchWelcomeFragment() {
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<WelcomeFragment> {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
            navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.welcomeFragment)
            this.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                    // The fragment’s view has just been created
                    Navigation.setViewNavController(this.requireView(), navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

After runnig test i got this error

[image: Error after runnig test]

Comment: Did you create a CustomTestRunner and add to the defaultConfig e.g defaultConfig { testInstrumentationRunner "com...CustomTestRunner" } ?

Comment: As a quick response you "cannot" test directly fragments with espresso. Please see this [article](https://medium.com/pulselive/espresso-testing-with-hilt-and-mockwebserver-82f7bcf5a525). I cannot help you further cuz I am currently trying to understand it!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use different activity in your test rather than using your real activity. in your fragment, there is some code that casting the activity that you get in that fragment to your real activity. this doesn't work because you are using different activity in your test that is HiltTestActivity. try to cast it to activity class that is more general like Activity or AppCompatActivity.